# SwiftUI: Passing Data between ViewModels

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, viewmodel

Let me explain my problem/question on simple example.

I have first view: `UserView` and realted `UserViewModel`.
I have second view: `UserDetailsView` and related `UserDetailsViewModel`

In `UserViewModel` I'm loading `User` object.
And then, I want pass `User` object to `UserDetailsViewModel`
So that `UserDetailsViewModel` could manipulate with User object.

Just to be clear, from clean code perspective, I don't want to keep `User` object in my Views.
View should work only with `ViewModel`

And here is a code:

```
struct UserView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = UserViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.user?.name ?? "")
            
            if let userDetailsViewModel = viewModel.userDetailsViewModel {
                NavigationLink {
                    UserDetailsView(viewModel: userDetailsViewModel)
                } label: {
                    Text("See user Details")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var userDetailsViewModel: UserDetailsViewModel?

    func fetchUser() {
        APIClient.shared.loadUser { user in
            self.user = user
            self.userDetailsViewModel = = .init(user:
                Binding(
                    get: {
                        self.user
                    },
                    set: {
                        self.user = $0
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }
}


struct UserDetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UserDetailsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack { 
            Text(viewModel.user.name)
            Text(viewModel.user.details)
        }
    }
}

class UserDetailsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var user: User

    init(user: Binding<User>) {
        _user = user
    }

    func updateUserName(_ name: String) {
        APIClient.shared.updateUserName(name) { user in
            self.user = user
        }
    }
}
```

I pass `User` as `@Binding` because I want `UserView` to be updates if `UserDetailsView` done some updates.

And the problem is:
If in `UserDetailsView` I call `updateUserName()`, then `UserDetailsView` is not updated.
Because `ViewModel` is a class. And only `@Published` can updated `View`.

I know one possible solution:
It is to add `@Published var userName: String` to `UserDetailsViewModel`.
And then update this property in `updateUserName()`.

But I really feel that It's more a workaround rather then a solution.
What if `User` has many properties that I want to display in `UserDetailsViewModel`?
Then I should create `@Published` property for each ?
Or create a separate `@Published var publishedUser` ?

Can some one tell me what is the best/correct way to achieve my goal ?
Thank you

Comment: View models shouldn’t know about each other and shouldn’t be connected. Move any data that can be used by both down a layer to a manager/store

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already (SwiftUI diffs the view struct data to create/update/remove actual UIViews automatically) so it is fine to store the User in `@State` in the View struct, that's what its for. You can use the `.task` modifier to start an async network download, it's started when the underlying `UIView` appears and cancelled when it disappears. It would be more work to do that using an object and you might get a leak if not done correctly.